# How can I force a refresh of the login console?

Tags: scripts, console

I used to have a script that would update `/etc/issue` with a few items such as IP address. However I setup a 16.04 server and the login screen does not update when updates are made to `/etc/issue`.

Is it possible to force the login console to refresh? I used to update the issue file every minute, but I no longer see the console update when new data is written to `/etc/issue`. I do see that if I hit <kbd>enter</kbd>, the new data will be there, but I am looking to update that automatically.

Comment: use something like `watch -d -n 60 'tail /etc/issue'` maybe  (-d highlights differences if you like it, -n 60 for 60 seconds)

Comment: This would be great, but is there a way to have this run on startup to show on the login console? It's for a device that runs like an appliance and I want to have the watch output showing on every startup.

Comment: add it to your .bash_profile (or another appropriate file depending on your use case; it will show up after login.... the file used can decide first login, each login etc..)

Comment: I unfortunately use this to give to clients where we send them an appliance with a small lcd monitor. I used to use this to output the ip and status info so they can tell if the box is online. No one will ever really login :(

Comment: After hours of searching I found that the same thing can be forced by resetting the console via agetty:

`sudo systemctl restart getty@tty1`

Answer (score 1):

Solved with the following:

```
sudo systemctl restart getty@tty1
```